# jquery, css, image grid layout with masonry

Tags: jquery, css, grid, html, jquery-masonry

I'm using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin but I'm trying to accomplish a multi column layout (probably 3 columns) and have 1 column with a large image and 2 other columns with smaller images, similar to the one in this [instagrams](http://instagram.com/instagram) grid layout at the top.

I can crop my images to be squares, but I'm not sure how to have 1 large image, and 4 smaller images (2 images per column), and the images should be able to size depending on the parent div width. Does Masonry have an option like this? or is this something to do with CSS or is there another jQuery plugin that I can combine with Masonry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use percentage-based widths, and as long as you size your divs properly, Masonry should take care of the rest.  The important piece is to set your `columnWidth` as a CSS selector to one of the smaller divs.  See http://jsfiddle.net/7Xp4T/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="square bigsquare"></div>
    <div class="square littlesquare"></div>
    <div class="square littlesquare"></div>
    <div class="square littlesquare"></div>
    <div class="square littlesquare"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
}
.square {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.bigsquare {
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
.littlesquare {
    width: 20%;
    height: 50%;
    background: blue;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var $container = $('#container');
// initialize
$container.masonry({
  columnWidth: '.littlesquare',
  itemSelector: '.square'
});
```

Comment: If my images are coming through a loop (from database), I wouldn't be able to add two different classes on them. Do you have a suggestion on how I can add different class names for something looped?

Comment: Does it matter which images are big and which ones are small?  If not, you could keep a global counter variable, and do a mod check (i % 5 === 0) for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: no it doesn't matter which images are small or big. I'm making all image uploads larger than what is going to be displayed. But the displaying image can be random. Maybe in the future I'll have certain images be the larger ones and certain ones be smaller, probably in this case the newest update will be larger

Comment: what does that mod check do? I'm a little new to programming, and still getting the hang of conditions

Comment: It basically does a division, but returns the remainder.  For example, 9 % 5 = 4.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation for more details.

Here's an updated jsFiddle with new squares being added every 5 seconds.  http://jsfiddle.net/7Xp4T/1/

Comment: I'm trying to work with your code, but my issue is that I'm already displaying the images on loading, and not adding the images. Your method seems to work excellent when adding images because it'll append new class names, but how do I do it such that I don't have to luxury to separately name my images? I can't name bigsquare and littlesquare  separately to begin with because my divs are in a loop. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're having trouble with.  Can you share your code with me?  I might have better luck helping you if I can see what you've accomplished so far.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35208/discussion-between-towler-and-andrewliu)